# Correct way to design a shopping cart websites database

Tags: database-design

I am in a web applications course. My instructor really didn't like the layout of my database, saying it was incorrect in pretty much every way. Fast forward 2 months when I'm remaking the website in a new language. I can't for the life of me see what's wrong. What is the correct way of making this layout? I have to use these and only these tables.

```
regUsers:
un
addr
PK uID
email
etc
```

Links to orders on mutual PK uID

```
orders:
orderID
pk uID

Links to orderDetail on orderID

orderDetail:
PK orderID
total
items (list)
date
address
```

Each item in items links to products. Not sure how to write a formal link between a list of Product IDs to the product table in MS SQL server 2008

```
product:
PK prodectNo
Pname
notes
price
imgpath
stock
```

Which links to productType on productNo PK

```
Product Type:
productNo
type
```

Comment: Take a look at [**this design**](http://ayende.com/blog/3738/designing-a-shopping-cart), it might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with your schema is the OrderDetail table: you have mixed data which is atomic (the date, the address) along with repeating data - the products ordered.

Your Orders table should be as follows

```
OrderId (primary key)
OrderNumber 
UserID (foreign key to users)
OrderDate
```

(address really belongs to the user)

whereas the OrderLines table should be as follows

```
OrderLine (primary key)
OrderId (foreign key to orders)
PartID (foreign key to products)
Quant
Price
Discount
Total (although this can be calculated as quant * price * (100 - discount) * 0.01)
```

Each order line has a total but there should **not** be a 'total' field in the orders table; instead, calculate this from the orderlines table.

The 'OrderLine' field might be redundant, if 'OrderId' and 'PartId' can be used as a composite primary key, which would mean that no part can appear twice in the same order. This might seem reasonable, but if you add fields such as 'supply date' (the date by which the customer wants to receive each part), you would have problems if a customer orders 100 widgets to be supplied by the end of December and another 100 widgets to be supplied by the end of January. The surrogate key (orderline) is probably the safest and easiest option.

Comment: I think the composite primary key works even in the case you've described. It doesn't really make a difference for the layout when items are supposed to be dispatched. That's something for the programming layer to deal with, not the DB's.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to try to layout the tables a little clearer, just so I'm sure we are on the same page.

```
regUsers( uID PK, un, addr, email, etc);
orders( uID PK,orderID);
orderDetail( PK orderID, total, items (list), date, address);
product( prodectNo PK, Pname, notes, price, imgpath, stock);
Product_Type( productNo, type);
```

If you had given SQL then I could have probably told you what your instructor disliked. For now I can only offer guesses.

> Each item in items links to products. Not sure how to write a formal link between a list of Product IDs to the product table in MS SQL server 2008

Are you familiar with the concept of foreign keys? If the answer is "no", then this is probably something your professor didn't like. Taking your `regUsers` and `orders` table as an example, you may want to use something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE regUsers(
 uID INT PRIMARY KEY,
 un VARCHAR,
 addr VARCHAR,
 email VARCHAR,
 etc VARCHAR);

CREATE TABLE orders(
 uID INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES regUsers(uID),
 orderID INT);
```

I selected `VARCHAR` somewhat arbitrarily because I don't know anything about the data you plan on storing. The important part is that the `uID` in `orders REFERENCES regUsers(uID)`. This means that all `uID` values in your `orders` table must also exist in your `regUsers` table.

Another point of interest here: you claim that you want `uID` to be the PK of `orders`, but `uID` is also the PK of `regUsers` (its foreign key). This implies that every `uID` in `regUsers` can have at most ONE row in the `orders` table... is that what you intended? Recall that PKs are unique.

> Which links to productType on productNo PK

Same issue with your `Product Type` table. If you are going to make `product_no` your PK for that table, then you can only have one row for each `product_no`; I don't think this is what you want. If it is what you want, and every `product_no` can have at most one `type`, then you might consider just storing the `type` in the `product` table and avoiding the `Product Type` table all together.

Another possible point, what did you mean by (list)? I did a quick search to see if there is a `LIST` data type in MS SQL server and found nothing. Are you planning on storing a list of strings in this column? If so, then it is a good candidate for a separate table all together.

Have you thought at all about the queries you would need to execute in order to get the information you need? What data types did you assign each column? In general, a good way to start designing a schema is to create an E/R diagram, but in this case you may need to do a little more research. I could be wrong here as well, and I would be glad to revise my response if you provide the actual SQL you are using to create the tables.

Answer (score 0):

There is few things you should always remember whenever you create a database -

1. Use foreign keys.
2. Use proper table names so not only you any developer can understand that without any problem.
3. Use proper table column names.
4. Use proper column data types.
5. Use proper initials if you use same name for two different objects in database. Like if you use stored procedures for Orders table. Then you should use table name as "tbl_Orders" and stored procedure name as "prc_Orders".

An example for table columns -

```
Create table tbl_Orders
(
Order_ID int identity primary key,
Customer_ID int,
Order_Date date,
Order_Time time,
Ship_Date date,
Shipping_Method int,

foreign key (Cust_ID) references tbl_Cusomers(Cust_ID),
foreign key (Shipping_Method) references tbl_Shipping(Ship_ID)
)
```